# How to face a patch in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

I have:

`ask Anas-discors[ let targ one-of patches with[pcolor = 88 ] if targ != nobody [set heading towards targ fd 1] ]`

This bird should fly to blue patches (pcolor 88) and only those patches, however this code is making my birds twitch a lot and then the agglomerate at the center of the map. I just want the to jump from on blue patch to another.

Comment: You can replace `set heading towards targ` with `face targ`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each turtle is identifying a different target blue patch each time it moves, so it is constantly changing directions.

If you want each turtle to keep moving toward its target until it gets there, you will need to make the target a turtles-own variable and not change it between when the turtle starts moving and when it arrives. The code may need to be a bit more complex: you will need separate statements for identifying the target patch (executed only when birds have not yet set their target), and for moving (repeated), and perhaps for what the bird does when it arrives at its target.